# i hv 2 table user is admin(user_id,status),user_profile(student_profile_id,user_id) update status in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

My model:

```
function update_client1($student_profile_id,$update_data,$status)
{
    $this->db->where('student_profile_id', $student_profile_id);  
    $query=$this->db->update('User_Profile',$update_data);  

    $this->db->where('status',$status) ;
    $query=$this->db->update('User',$update_data);

    $report = array();

    $report['error'] = $this->db->_error_number();
    $report['message'] = $this->db->_error_message();
    if($report !== 0){

        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get the following error in display:

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 1054
>   Unknown column 'firstname' in 'field list'
>
> ```
> UPDATE `User` SET `firstname` = 'minu1', `lastname` = 's12', `email` = 's@rw.m',
> `phone_number` = '0123654799', `city` = 'ahmedabad', `state` = 'gujarat',
> `country` = 'india', `subject_id` = '20' WHERE `status` IS NULL
> ```
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\ekta\example\system\database\DB_driver.php
>   Line Number: 330

How can I fix this?

Comment: i hv update 2 table user(status) and user_profile (all fields)

Comment: Confirm if column 'firstname' is present in user table

Comment: show the `$update`  array  and fields of the 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("admin/post_model");
    $this->load->model("admin/comment_model");
}
    public function index(){
    $data['post_res'] = $this->post_model->getPost();
    $data['com_res']  = $this->post_model->getComments();
    }
 }
```